Blur event flow and synchronization of DOM updates
The following code has this behavior when I focus on the input and then click the delete button:

Mousedown callback function is triggered, however input does not blur immediately cause of ev.preventDefault()

Container gets removed by (at least it should be) the mousedown function.

Blur callback function is then triggered since the removal of the container caused the input to lose focus

It prints the container element in the console, even though I was expecting null. Wasn't it removed by the mousedown callback function?

It then (in my understanding) removes the container element that for some reason was not removed by the mousedown func.

the mousedown func then doesn't find an element to remove so it throws a DOMException.


I am not sure if the process happens exactly like I described it. If I comment out the container.remove line in the blur func, first the element will be printed in the console by the blur func and after "null" will be printed by the mousedown func.
I cannot understand how the blur func is seemingly called before the mousedown one. For the blur func to be called the container has to be removed. So how does the blur func find it in the DOM again and how does it remove it if it's already been removed?


const inp = document.querySelector("input");
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("mousedown", (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log('Before remove',document.querySelector("#container"));  
  container.remove();
  console.log('After remove',document.querySelector("#container"));
});

inp.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  console.log('In blur',document.querySelector("#container"));
  container.remove();
});
<div id="container">
  <input />
  <button>Delete</button>
</div>




The blur is called when the button is clicked

I also thought that at first. The issue is that e.preventDefault() on the mousedown event  supposedly stops the input from being blurred. if I comment out the container.remove() line in the mousedown callback , I will be able to just keep clicking on the "Delete" button forever, without the input losing focus. It confused me even more that this was not the answer.

Why would you want to remove <input> on blur? If the user actually enters something into the <input> then clicks anywhere (not just the <button>), the user has no option of going back and changing what was entered. That's bad UX.

I've added a few try-catch statements for you to make it easier to understand what happens. The error is clearly raised in the mousedown handler, because the blur handler is executed before the container.remove() line inside the mousedown handler.
The "flow" therefor seems to be:

mousedown triggers on button
ev.preventDefault() is called in mousedown handler
console.log('Before remove', /* elided */) is executed in mousedown handler
blur triggers on input
console.log('In blur', /* elided */) is executed in blur handler
container.remove() is executed in blur handler
container.remove() is executed in mousedown handler (fails since container is already removed)

For the sake of completeness, I added a focus listener to the button, just to make sure that all relevant steps are captured. However, focus is never executed (makes sense, the default action would include setting the focus to the button and the .preventDefault() prevents the default action from happening).

I've only checked this in Chrome Stable 127.0, so maybe other browsers
behave different (although I doubt it).



const inp = document.querySelector("input");
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const btn = document.querySelector("button");

btn.addEventListener("mousedown", (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log('Before remove',document.querySelector("#container"));
  try {
    container.remove();
  } catch (exc) {
    console.log('Error in mousedown', exc);
  }
  console.log('After remove',document.querySelector("#container"));
});

btn.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  console.log('Button has focus now');
});

inp.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  console.log('In blur',document.querySelector("#container"));
  try {
    container.remove();
  } catch (exc) {
    console.log('Error in blur', exc);
  }
});
<div id="container">
  <input />
  <button>Delete</button>
</div>



